# How to give option whether clients want json response or jsonp based on web api request

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, jsonp

I have developed a web api in that I have implemented jsonp for mater like

```
 var jsonpFormatter =
                new JsonpMediaTypeFormatter(formatters.JsonFormatter);
 formatters.Insert(0, jsonpFormatter);
```

and I am able to consume it using jsonp using below mentioned request

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "http://localhost:61734/api/baseapi",
            callback: 'returnCallBack',
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'jsonp'
        });
```

my question how can we make our api which can identify based on request whether response should be json or jsonp. can anyone please help I want based on my request API give me json or jsonp response.

Answer (score 0):

There are several nuget packages out there that can do this for you so you don't have to reinvent the wheel.  E.g. [WebApiContrib.Formatting.JsonP](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebApiContrib.Formatting.Jsonp/)

if you don't want to use another library though then the basis of what they are doing is to create a new MediaTypeFormatter that will inspect the request for a callback parameter indicating that it is JsonP and wrap the serialised response with "Callbackname(" + json + ");"